# Why are a majority of the namecoin sync messages "ConnectInputsHook() not in pending - must be someone elses"

Tags: namecoin

I'm comparing the run time debug logs of namecoin and bitcoin and noticed that much of namecoin's initial sync processing is dominated by the following command:

```
ConnectInputsHook() : connecting inputs on bd3dd490663d35b1bb4f196335e84d84148c7f5573acb0f7c993dcfffe6fdf35 which was not in pending - must be someone elses
ConnectInputsHook() : connecting inputs on 93a1fc009d5bda3f2670c3b8a40eebaead3128d83762346106fba6af4bd87b45 which was not in pending - must be someone elses
ConnectInputsHook() : connecting inputs on d654e34b29e1cbd2c14b8437b020b7bf24b0366a39acb0eb7e754581e7100af8 which was not in pending - must be someone else's
```

... of course the inputs vary, but I'm at block 4300 and I'm getting tons of these "errors".  What causes these messages and is that normal going forward?  (what are the conditions that cause these messages)?